# При нажатии не меняются валюты и курс валют

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема с конвертером, вроде исправил, что мне подсказывали, но при нажатии на кнопку со стрелками, чтобы поменять валюты, то в консоли постоянно жалуется на `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rate')`, также у выпадающем списке постоянно пишет undefined, не могу понять в чем проблема, как это исправить?

```js
//take the selected option (first one in array)
let currencyOne = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-select__option--select')[0];
//take the selected option (secondone in array)
let currencyTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-select__option--select')[1];
const amountOne = document.getElementById('amount-two');
const amountTwo = document.getElementById('amount-two');
const rates = document.getElementById('rate');
const swap = document.getElementById('swap');

// Fetch exchange rates and update the dome
function converter() {
  //take the currency en make it three chars long
  const currency_one = currencyOne.textContent.trim().slice(0, 3);
  const currency_two = currencyTwo.textContent.trim().slice(0, 3);
  

  fetch(`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {  
    
    data.unshift({"txt":"Українська гривня", "rate": 1, "cc":"UAH"})
            
      currency1 = data.find(item => item.cc === currency_one);
      currency2 = data.find(item => item.cc === currency_two);

      rates.innerText =  `1 ${currency_one} = ${(1 * currency1.rate / currency2.rate).toFixed(4)} ${currency_two}`;
      amountTwo.value = (amountOne.value !== '') ? (amountOne.value * currency1.rate / currency2.rate).toFixed(2) : '';
    });
}

converter();

// Event Listeners
currencyOne.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountOne.addEventListener('input', converter);
currencyTwo.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountTwo.addEventListener('input', converter);

swap.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const temp = currencyOne.value;
  currencyOne.innerHTML = '';
  currencyOne.append(currencyTwo);
  currencyTwo.innerHTML = '';
  currencyTwo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(temp));
  converter();
});


[...document.querySelectorAll(".custom-select")].map(select => {
  let selected = select.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select");
  if (selected) {
    select.dataset.value = selected.dataset.value;
    const placeholder = select.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder");
    placeholder.innerHTML = "";
    const pho = selected.cloneNode(true);
    pho.classList.remove("custom-select__option--select"); 
    placeholder.appendChild(pho);
  }

  select.querySelector(".custom-select__list").addEventListener("click", e => {
    let target = e.target.closest(".custom-select__option");
    if (target) {
      let parent = target.closest(".custom-select");

      parent.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select").classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
      target.classList.add("custom-select__option--select");
      let selected = parent.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select");

      parent.dataset.value = selected.dataset.value;

      const placeholder = parent.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder");
      placeholder.innerHTML = "";
      const pho = selected.cloneNode(true);
      pho.classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
      placeholder.appendChild(pho);

    }
  });

  select.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder").
  addEventListener("click", e => {
    let target = e.target.closest(".custom-select__placeholder");
    if (target) {
      target.closest(".custom-select").classList.toggle("custom-select--drop");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.custom-select {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
          z-index: 1;
          margin-bottom: 8.7px;
}

.custom-select:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.custom-select:focus {
  color: #8dc641;
}

.custom-select__list {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 12px);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.custom-select--drop .custom-select__list {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.custom-select--drop .custom-select__placeholder::after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg);
}
.custom-select__option {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}
.custom-select__option-icon {
  display: block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.custom-select__option-icon img {
  display: block;
  width: 18px; 
  height: 15px;
  max-height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
.custom-select__option-name {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.custom-select__option-symbol {
  display: block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.custom-select__option:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.045);
}
.custom-select__option--select .custom-select__option-name {
  color: #8dc641;
}
.custom-select__placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.custom-select__placeholder::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top-width: 6px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.custom-select__option {
  padding-right: calc(1.5em + 10px);
}
.custom-select__option:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}



/* .container {
  
  border: solid 2px #212121;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
} */

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indent-right {
  display: flex; 
  width: 24px; 
  height: 24px; 
  background-image: url("https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/ServiceCurrency.svg"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center center; 
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 57px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 450ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  word-break: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.swap-rate-container .btn-arrows {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0.54;
  transition: opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.currency {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

.currency input {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 65%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin-left: 15px
}

.currency input:hover {
  display:block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.currency input:focus {
  border-color: #8dc641;
}

.currency-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

/* .currency input::after {
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.currency input::before {
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.currency input:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.currency input:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
} */

.select-placeholder {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

.swap-rate-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.rate {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  line-height: var(--tl-small);
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (maz-width: 600px) {
  .currency input {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Currency Converter</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="currencies-icon-10.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="indent-right"></div>
        <b>Конвертор валют</b>
      </div>
      <div class="currency">
<div class="custom-select">
  <div class="custom-select__placeholder"></div>
  <div class="custom-select__list">
    <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="EUR">
      <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/EU.svg"/></div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-name">EUR</div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">€</div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-select__option custom-select__option--select" data-value="USD">
      <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/US.svg"/></div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-name">USD</div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">$</div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="GBP">
      <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/GB.svg"/></div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-name">GBP</div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">£</div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="UAH">
      <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/UA.svg"/></div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-name">UAH</div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">₴</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        <input id="amount-one" placeholder="200.00" />
      </div>

      <div class="swap-rate-container">
        <button class="btn" id="swap">
        <div class="btn-arrows">
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <svg
            height="24px"
            width="24px"
            version="1.1"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <g
              fill="none"
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              stroke="none"
              stroke-width="1"
            >
              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M6.99 11L3 15l3.99 4v-3H14v-2H6.99v-3zM21 9l-3.99-4v3H10v2h7.01v3L21 9z"
                fill="#000"
                fill-rule="nonzero"
              ></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
        <div class="rate" id="rate"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="currency">
<div class="custom-select">
  <div class="custom-select__placeholder"></div>
  <div class="custom-select__list">
    <div class="custom-select__option custom-select__option--select" data-value="UAH">
      <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/UA.svg"/></div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-name">UAH</div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">₴</div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="GBP">
      <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/GB.svg"/></div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-name">GBP</div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">£</div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="EUR">
      <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/EU.svg"/></div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-name">EUR</div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">€</div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="USD">
      <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/US.svg"/></div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-name">USD</div>
      <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">$</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        <input id="amount-two" placeholder="200.00" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если честно не очень сильно смог разобраться в вашем коде, потому применил хитрый трюк:

- Объявил заранее переменные `select1` и `select2`
- При свайпе, я просто в каждом из списков нахожу элемент, у которого `data-value` такое же как у выбранного элемента в другом списке
- А потом просто имтирую клик на них

Функция свапа:

```
swap.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const [value1, value2] = [select1, select2].map(select => select.querySelector('.custom-select__option--select').dataset.value);
  
  select1.querySelector(`[data-value="${value2}"]`).click();
  select2.querySelector(`[data-value="${value1}"]`).click();  
  converter();
});
```

```js
const [select1, select2] = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select');
const [currencyOne, currencyTwo] = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select__option--select');
const amountOne = document.getElementById('amount-two');
const amountTwo = document.getElementById('amount-two');
const rates = document.getElementById('rate');
const swap = document.getElementById('swap');

function converter() {
  const currency_one = currencyOne.textContent.trim().slice(0, 3);
  const currency_two = currencyTwo.textContent.trim().slice(0, 3);

  fetch(`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {

      data.unshift({
        "txt": "Українська гривня",
        "rate": 1,
        "cc": "UAH"
      })

      currency1 = data.find(item => item.cc === currency_one);
      currency2 = data.find(item => item.cc === currency_two);

      rates.innerText = `1 ${currency_one} = ${(1 * currency1.rate / currency2.rate).toFixed(4)} ${currency_two}`;
      amountTwo.value = (amountOne.value !== '') ? (amountOne.value * currency1.rate / currency2.rate).toFixed(2) : '';
    });
}

converter();

currencyOne.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountOne.addEventListener('input', converter);
currencyTwo.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountTwo.addEventListener('input', converter);

swap.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const [value1, value2] = [select1, select2].map(select => select.querySelector('.custom-select__option--select').dataset.value);
  
  select1.querySelector(`[data-value="${value2}"]`).click();
  select2.querySelector(`[data-value="${value1}"]`).click();  
  converter();
});

[...document.querySelectorAll(".custom-select")].map(select => {
  let selected = select.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select");
  if (selected) {
    select.dataset.value = selected.dataset.value;
    const placeholder = select.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder");
    placeholder.innerHTML = "";
    const pho = selected.cloneNode(true);
    pho.classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
    placeholder.appendChild(pho);
  }

  select.querySelector(".custom-select__list").addEventListener("click", e => {
    let target = e.target.closest(".custom-select__option");
    if (target) {
      let parent = target.closest(".custom-select");

      parent.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select").classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
      target.classList.add("custom-select__option--select");
      let selected = parent.querySelector(".custom-select__option--select");

      parent.dataset.value = selected.dataset.value;

      const placeholder = parent.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder");
      placeholder.innerHTML = "";
      const pho = selected.cloneNode(true);
      pho.classList.remove("custom-select__option--select");
      placeholder.appendChild(pho);

    }
  });

  select.querySelector(".custom-select__placeholder").
  addEventListener("click", e => {
    let target = e.target.closest(".custom-select__placeholder");
    if (target) {
      target.closest(".custom-select").classList.toggle("custom-select--drop");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.custom-select {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 8.7px;
}

.custom-select:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.custom-select:focus {
  color: #8dc641;
}

.custom-select__list {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 12px);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.custom-select--drop .custom-select__list {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.custom-select--drop .custom-select__placeholder::after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg);
}

.custom-select__option {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}

.custom-select__option-icon {
  display: block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.custom-select__option-icon img {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 15px;
  max-height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.custom-select__option-name {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.custom-select__option-symbol {
  display: block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.custom-select__option:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.045);
}

.custom-select__option--select .custom-select__option-name {
  color: #8dc641;
}

.custom-select__placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.custom-select__placeholder::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top-width: 6px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.custom-select__option {
  padding-right: calc(1.5em + 10px);
}

.custom-select__option:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* .container {
  
  border: solid 2px #212121;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
} */

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indent-right {
  display: flex;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/ServiceCurrency.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 57px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 450ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  word-break: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.swap-rate-container .btn-arrows {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0.54;
  transition: opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.currency {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.currency input {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 65%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin-left: 15px
}

.currency input:hover {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.currency input:focus {
  border-color: #8dc641;
}

.currency-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}


/* .currency input::after {
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.currency input::before {
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.currency input:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.currency input:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
} */

.select-placeholder {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

.swap-rate-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.rate {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  line-height: var(--tl-small);
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (maz-width: 600px) {
  .currency input {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="indent-right"></div>
    <b>Конвертор валют</b>
  </div>
  <div class="currency">
    <div class="custom-select">
      <div class="custom-select__placeholder"></div>
      <div class="custom-select__list">
        <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="EUR">
          <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/EU.svg" /></div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-name">EUR</div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">€</div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select__option custom-select__option--select" data-value="USD">
          <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/US.svg" /></div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-name">USD</div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">$</div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="GBP">
          <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/GB.svg" /></div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-name">GBP</div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">£</div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="UAH">
          <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/UA.svg" /></div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-name">UAH</div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">₴</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input id="amount-one" placeholder="200.00" />
  </div>

  <div class="swap-rate-container">
    <button class="btn" id="swap">
        <div class="btn-arrows">
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <svg
            height="24px"
            width="24px"
            version="1.1"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <g
              fill="none"
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              stroke="none"
              stroke-width="1"
            >
              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M6.99 11L3 15l3.99 4v-3H14v-2H6.99v-3zM21 9l-3.99-4v3H10v2h7.01v3L21 9z"
                fill="#000"
                fill-rule="nonzero"
              ></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <div class="rate" id="rate"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="currency">
    <div class="custom-select">
      <div class="custom-select__placeholder"></div>
      <div class="custom-select__list">
        <div class="custom-select__option custom-select__option--select" data-value="UAH">
          <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/UA.svg" /></div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-name">UAH</div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">₴</div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="GBP">
          <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/GB.svg" /></div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-name">GBP</div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">£</div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="EUR">
          <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/EU.svg" /></div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-name">EUR</div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">€</div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select__option" data-value="USD">
          <div class="custom-select__option-icon"><img src="https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/US.svg" /></div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-name">USD</div>
          <div class="custom-select__option-symbol">$</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input id="amount-two" placeholder="200.00" />
  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: О, спасибо, да, работает, а как сделать, чтобы курс считало, а то получается, что валюты меняются между собой, это хорошо, а курс не считает, как это исправить?

Comment: Так у вас курс не считается и без свапа, я просто имитировал нажатие. Или это у вас второй вопрос?)

Comment: А, наверное второй вопрос, я просто думал, что он не считался, из-за этой проблемы, что оно не переключалось, а когда будет исправлено, то все будет считать, я так думал

Comment: Бывает) Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пожалуйста принять его, поставив зелёную галочку слева от ответа

Comment: Да, хорошо, так а что все таки с курсом, чтобы считал, как это исправить? Или это мне надо заново создавать вопрос?

Comment: Можно создавать вопрос, а можно просто правильно переменные объявить) Вы два раза ищите `amount-two'`, а вам надо `amount-one` в первый раз